# Observing database using flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I am having trouble to implement this feature below.

Let's say I hava a Content class.

```
interface ContentDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertContent(content: Content)

    @Query("query to get content with id")
    fun getContent(contentId: Long): Flow<Content>
}
```

I should not directly observe this in ui layer. Instead i need something like this

```
fun getContent(contentId: Long) : Flow<State> = flow {
    emit(State.Loading)
    val response = handle {api.getContent(contentId)}
    if (response !is Success) {
        emit(State.Error)
        return@flow
    } else {
        appDatabase.contentDao.insertContent(response.getContent())

        appDatabase.contentDao.getContent(contentId).collect {
            emit(State.Content(it))
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement this behaviour. Collector should not directly observe appdatabase. First it should update content. Then listen to database.

If something went wrong while updating content. It should emit Error state.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already posted?

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the insert function by throwing Exception if something went wrong:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
@Throws(SQLiteException::class)
suspend fun insertContent(content: Content)
```

and also in your case, I think you don't need to return flow in your content:

```
@Query("query to get content with id")
@Throws(SQLiteException::class)
suspend fun getContent(contentId: Long): Content
```

and in your function do this:

```
fun getContent(contentId: Long) : Flow<State> = flow {
    emit(State.Loading)
    val response = handle {api.getContent(contentId)}
    if (response !is Success) {
        emit(State.Error)
        return@flow
    } else {
        try {
            appDatabase.contentDao.insertContent(response.getContent())
            emit(appDatabase.contentDao.getContent(contentId))
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
            emit(State.Error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually returning flow from @Dao is needed. Bacause, once content loaded some changes are applied to database according to user's action. So the Dao must return observable response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. From the code that I posted in my question, I was getting an exception. Because i was emitting value to a flow from different coroutine. I used channelFlow builder function (which hanldles communication between coruotines) instead of flow builder. Now everything is working fine.

For more details, you can see the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).